Analyzing website traffic data across different timezones
I haven't seen how different analytics platform document this type of information, but I was thinking about the difference in how you might analyze user behaviour on a website or social media account based on audiences in different timezones (which results in a difference in the day and time when they interact with the site).
In terms of posting content, there would be a difference in the day that you post content in one timezone to the day when someone in another part of the world sees it. Of course, you might have some sophisticated setup where you can post content to the site so that it is at a specific day/time for a particular country, but you can't do this for multiple countries/timezones (as far as I know).
As for people viewing content on the website, it would be a lot easier to normalize the data because you can simply collect details about the country where the traffic is from and convert it to the same day/time. This seems to make sense because you don't want to compare the day/time to a fixed reference point because there are patterns across the week.
For example, I create a post and publish it in Australia and it goes live on a website. People who see this post and read it will most likely be doing this on a different day (due to timezone differences), and you would want to know whether this is an optimal time to post the content (or if you should post it at a different time for those audiences). But for people who visit the website normally, you don't need to differentiate between the different timezones because the data just needs to be to their local time and reported in the same way (because you want to compare the same day in different timezones).
If you want analyze the change to the website based on content that you post, how can you reconcile the differences between how you would track and process information for posting content and for general traffic to the website or social media profile? Is it even a significant enough issue to worry about?

I don't understand the question, I feel :-(  Do you want to analyze how long it takes until a post is read/shared when posting and the reaction happen in different timezones? Or do you want to compare reaction times (to the same post) between different timezones? And by "you can't do this for multiple countries/timezones" - you mean, it's not been implemented anywhere?

@virtualnobi I want to analyze the effect of adding content to the website across different audience groups. On platforms like Google Analytics, there is a lot of work to split the website traffic data by country, then by first time vs. returning visitors, and then by the various pages. However, I am not sure how to interpret the data for the days when content has been scheduled and published, because I don't know how the website traffic data is processed and aggregated.

Do you own server application which renders your website? Or are you looking for third-party analytics to integrate with some web-platform? These are two different tasks.

@Serg I am looking at this from the point of view of someone who consumes analytics data (e.g. UX designer that wants to make decisions about content to add to the website), and how the dashboards and reports provided by the platforms address this issue.
